# How to get top three words from the results tokenized in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to get the top three words in the results tokenized in NLTK. This is sorted by how often the words are used.

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

raw = open('sample.txt').read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)

tokens_l = [w.lower() for w in tokens]

pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens_l)

only_nn = [x for (x,y) in pos if y in ('NN')]

freq = nltk.FreqDist(only_nn)
print(freq.items())
```

results:

> dict_items([('everyone', 1), ('work', 15), ('ability', 7), ('determination', 3), ('ingredient', 2), ('understood', 1)])

I want to get `work`, `ability`, and `determination`. How can I get these three words from the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `freq.most_common(3)`, and collect the first items in the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
for word, frequency in freq.items().__reversed__():
    print("Word:", word, "Frequency:", frequency)
```

This is a dictionary so it is made up of key-value pairs. The loop just iterates through it.

The 'reversed' part sorts it in descending order.